# Laravel Form::select generation in blades template

Tags: laravel

This line of code:

```
{!!  Form::select('fightingAreas', [1,2,4,8], old('fightingAreas'),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Generates :

```
 <select class="form-control" id="fightingAreas" name="fightingAreas">  
    <option value="0" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">4</option>
    <option value="3">8</option>
 </select>
```

I would like to generate a value that is equals to text:

```
<select class="form-control" id="fightingAreas" name="fightingAreas">  
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
 </select>
```

Is it posible to do it with Form::select()???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually easier than you think

```
    {!!  Form::select('fightingAreas', 
         ['1'=>1,'2'=>2,'4'=>4,'8'=>8], 
         null,['class' => 'form-control']) 
    !!}
```

Also using null will automatically select the old value no need to set `old('fightingAreas')`

For more info have a look at

http://laravel-recipes.com/categories/21

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Thanks